C# WPF Virtualization across multiple ItemsControls that share a single scrollbar
I'm trying to virtualize a screen that contains multiple ItemsControls which share 1 scrollbar.
I can virtualize each ItemsControl independently but thats pretty ugly.
The height of each item be the same 90% of the time so don't need to support dynamic heights in the children.
I've tried to write my own CustomVirtualizingPanel but not winning, was trying to find an existing nuget package where this problem may have already been solved.
Many thanks,

When item containers are of the same type (which would be a prerequisite for "shared virtualization"), why do you have multiple ItemsControls in the first place?

This what the client requires, each populated from a different call and each with their own specific ordering and grouping.
I also have a similar requirement where I got 2 treeviews below each other which I need to try virtualize in the same scrollbar. Was hoping the same custom panel would work here, but got my doubts

There is one (Items)Panel instance per ItemsControl. Virtualization across multiple Panels seems complicated if not impossible.

if you had to remove itemscontrols from the equation, how would one virtualize a screen with alot of controls on it ? Would have thought the same/similar would work here

Why CustomVirtualizingPanel have failed? What it was supposed to do? How your not working XAML code looks like?

Why can't you just have the one datagrid or listview? Put all your data in there?
